Geodesics (definition)
I have a doubt about the definition of geodesic curve on a regular surface: I know that a geodesic on a regular surface $S\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is, by definition, a curve $C$ such that its geodesic curvature (that is, the projection of the curvature vector $K_C$ on the tangent plane) is always zero or, equivalently, if $\gamma :I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ is a regular parametrization of $C$, then the vector field $\gamma'$ is parallel along $C$ (that is, $\nabla_{\gamma'(t)}\gamma'=0$, where $\nabla$ indicates the covariant derivative). However, this means that $C$ is parametrized at constant velocity because its acceleration is totally normal. On the other hand, every curve can be parametrized at constant velocity, but not all the curves on a surface are geodesics.
So, my question is: Since every curve can be parametrized at constant velocity (for example by arc length), why it is not true that all (locally) regular curves on a surface are geodesics? Where is my mistake?

You are committing a basic logical fallacy: $A\Rightarrow B$ does not imply that $B\Rightarrow A$. Now, try to figure out what are $A$ and $B$ in your question. (Look for the word "means" in the post.)

Any curve has a constant speed parameterization. Only geodesics have a constant velocity parameterization.

The fact that a regular curve can be parametrized by arc length (constant speed) does not mean that every constant-speed parametrized curve is a geodesic. The defining characteristic of a geodesic is the vanishing of the geodesic curvature, not just the constancy of speed, that is only a consequence of being geodesic.
For a general curve $\alpha(t)$ on $S$, you can reparametrize it by arc length to get a new curve $\beta(s)$. This curve $\beta(s)$ has constant speed, but it may still have non-zero geodesic curvature.
For an explcit example, take a sphere and consider the following curves: the equator and another parallel, for example, the curve at latitude $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$ ($45$ degrees north of the equator). This curve can be parametrized by:
$$\alpha(t)=\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\cos(t), \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\sin(t), \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)$$
for $t\in [0,2\pi]$.
The equator is a geodesic, $\alpha(t)$ is not a geodesic even though it is arc-length parametrized.

Ok, so tell me if I am wrong: let $C$ be a regular curve on the surface $S$, parametrized by $\gamma: I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$; then, $T(t)=\frac{\gamma'(t)}{v(t)}$ is the tangent unit vector of the curve ($v(t)$ is the scalar velocity, that is, the norm of $\gamma'$). So, the acceleration $\gamma''(t)=v'(t)T(t)+v(t)T'(t)$, but calling $s$ the arc parameter we have, by Frenet formulas, that $T'(s)=k(s)N_C(s)$, but $T(s)=T(t(s))$, then $T'(s)=\frac{T'(t)}{v(t)}$. Thus, $\gamma''(t)=v'(t)T(t)+v(t)^2k(s)N_C(s)$ and $\nabla_{\gamma'(t)}\gamma'=v'(t)T(t)+v(t)^2k(s)N_C(s)$.

This means that if $\nabla_{\gamma'(t}} \gamma'=0$, then $v'(t)=0$, that is, the curve is parametrized ad constant velocity. However, the converse does not hold, because in that case $\nabla_{\gamma'(t}} \gamma'=0 \iff N_C(s)=N_S$ the normal unit vector of the surface

Ok, but I can't read the second comment because of an error in the latex syntax that you made ;(

This means that if $\nabla_{\gamma'(t)}\gamma'=0$, then $v'(t)=0$,  that is, the curve is parametrized at constant velocity. However, the converse does not hold, because in that case $\nabla_{\gamma'(t)}\gamma'=0 \iff N_C(s)=N_S$, the normal unit vector of the surface

Ok, therefore, the definition of geodesic makes sense.

Thanks for your help!
